# When I use $_POST in php , undefined index happened

Tags: php, forms, web-applications, post

I am a PHP programmer, I am confused with the problem below, I am waiting for your guide .
Thanks so much!
 There is the html code

```
 <form action="" method="POST">
    <div>
        <strong>Release: *</strong> <input type="text" name="Release" value="<?php echo $rel; ?>" /><br/>
        <strong>User Story ID: *</strong> <input type="text" name="User Story ID" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" /><br/>
        <strong>Test Owner *</strong> <input type="text" name="Test Owner" value="<?php echo $owner; ?>" /><br/>
        <strong>Date of TC Review *</strong> <input type="text" name="Date of TC Review" value="<?php echo $data; ?>" /><br/>
        <strong>By Design </strong> <input type="text" name="By Design" value="<?php echo $design; ?>" /><br/> 
        <strong>By Review </strong> <input type="text" name="By Review" value="<?php echo $review; ?>" /><br/> 
        <strong>By Defect </strong> <input type="text" name="By Defect" value="<?php echo $defect; ?>" /><br/> 
      <p>* required</p>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
 </form>
```

There is the php code

```
     if (isset($_POST['submit']))
     { 
        // get form data, making sure it is valid
         $release = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['Release']));
        //  $ID = " abc";
        echo $_POST['Release'];
        echo $_POST['User Story ID'];
        $ID = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST["User Story ID"]));
        $T_Owner = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['Test Owner']));
        $data = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['Date of TC Review']));
        $T_ByDesign= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['By Design']));
        $T_ByReview= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['By Review']));
        $T_ByDefect= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['By Defect']));

        // check to make sure both fields are entered
        if ($release == '' || $ID == ''||$T_Owner==''||$data=='')
        {
            // generate error message
            $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';

            // if either field is blank, display the form again
            renderForm($release, $ID, $T_Owner, $data, $T_ByDesign, $T_ByReview, $T_ByDefect, $error);
        }
        else
        {
            // save the data to the database
            mysql_query("INSERT Tests SET T_Release='$release', ID='$ID',TestOwner='$T_Owner',T_Date='$data',Test_ByDesign='$T_ByDesign',Test_ByReview='$T_ByReview',Test_ByDefect='$T_ByDefect'")
            or die(mysql_error()); 

            // once saved, redirect back to the view page
            header("Location: view.php"); 
        }
 }
```

And the error information is below:

```
Notice: Undefined index: User Story ID in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\new.php on line 47
abc
Notice: Undefined index: User Story ID in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\new.php on line 55

Notice: Undefined index: User Story ID in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\new.php on line 56

Notice: Undefined index: Test Owner in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\new.php on line 57

Notice: Undefined index: Date of TC Review in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\new.php on line 58

Notice: Undefined index: By Design in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\new.php on line 59

Notice: Undefined index: By Review in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\new.php on line 60

Notice: Undefined index: By Defect in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\new.php on line 61
```

Comment: @Deadlock  `action=""` that means same page :)

Comment: `echo $_POST['User Story ID'];`? It is not ideal to put spaces on your `name` tag.

Comment: It seems all the form elements with a space in their name are screwing up. What is the result for `print_r($_POST)` for the data you are sending it?

Answer (score 2):

You are using invalid name for form input element.
Don't include space in form name.

Comment: Spaces just get replaced, that's all. OP, just `var_dump` the `$_POST` and see how names were translated.

Answer (score 2):

1st edit your form:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<div>
    <strong>Release: *</strong> <input type="text" name="Release" value="<?php echo $rel; ?>" /><br/>
    <strong>User Story ID: *</strong> <input type="text" name="User_Story_ID" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" /><br/>
    <strong>Test Owner *</strong> <input type="text" name="Test_Owner" value="<?php echo $owner; ?>" /><br/>
    <strong>Date of TC Review *</strong> <input type="text" name="Date_of_TC_Review" value="<?php echo $data; ?>" /><br/>
    <strong>By Design </strong> <input type="text" name="By_Design" value="<?php echo $design; ?>" /><br/> 
    <strong>By Review </strong> <input type="text" name="By_Review" value="<?php echo $review; ?>" /><br/> 
    <strong>By Defect </strong> <input type="text" name="By_Defect" value="<?php echo $defect; ?>" /><br/> 
  <p>* required</p>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
```

don't use spaces on the form names, then you can get the post values like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 { 
       // get form data, making sure it is valid
      $release = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['Release']));

    echo Print_r($_POST['Release']);
    echo Print_r($_POST['User_Story_ID']);
    $ID = $_POST["User_Story_ID"];
    $T_Owner = $_POST['Test_Owner'];
    $data = $_POST['Date_of_TC_Review'];
    $T_ByDesign= $_POST['By_Design'];
    $T_ByReview= $_POST['By_Review'];
    $T_ByDefect= $_POST['By_Defect'];

    // check to make sure both fields are entered
if ($release == '' || $ID == ''||$T_Owner==''||$data=='')
{
    // generate error message
    $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';

    // if either field is blank, display the form again
    renderForm($release, $ID, $T_Owner, $data, $T_ByDesign, $T_ByReview, $T_ByDefect, $error);
}
else
{
    // save the data to the database
    mysql_query("INSERT Tests SET T_Release='$release', ID='$ID',TestOwner='$T_Owner',T_Date='$data',Test_ByDesign='$T_ByDesign',Test_ByReview='$T_ByReview',Test_ByDefect='$T_ByDefect'")
    or die(mysql_error()); 

    // once saved, redirect back to the view page
    header("Location: view.php"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all never use "By Design" kinds of coding in php or in any other programming instead of it you should use like this "By_Design" or use cameCaps(byDesign). What is $rel,$id and other stuffs in your html form, you didnot mentioned it. The main problem that is causing in your problem is the use of spaces in your forms and in php.Please don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried some test code:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="what happened" value="here" />
</form>
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

And it seems PHP replaces all elements with spaces in their names to underscores. Thus you'd want to use `$_POST['User_Story_ID']` instead of `$_POST['User Story ID']`. Etc.

Comment: you also have to change the name in the form to `User_Story_ID`.

Comment: It gets converted automatically by PHP so that isn't a required edit to make the code work necessarily. But it is good coding practice to use valid markup as well which will also prevent humans from getting confused.

Answer (score 0):

Add form action "`your_page.php`"

Example :  `<form action="your_page.php" method="POST">`

And remove space for form input element like:

```
echo $_POST['User Story ID'];
```

instead of this :

Example :

```
<strong>User Story ID: *</strong> <input type="text" name="UserStoryID" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" /><br/>
```

`echo $_POST['UserStoryID'];` or whatever you want to name it

Comment: if you put `$_POST['User_Story_ID'];` it will pawn the same error.

Comment: you also have to modify the name in the form to `UserStoryID`

Comment: @BlackHatShadow: I think you not read my answer properly. I just mention INSTEAD OF `echo $_POST['User Story ID'];` USE echo `$_POST['UserStoryID'];`

Comment: @vusan : Is this comment for me?

Comment: @vusan : sorry but Im not getting it

Comment: why action="your_page.php" instead of action="" as you know HTML form and PHP code are on same page.

Answer (score 0):

You should be define you variable before use. Please check one more time.